# how to disable certain UIButton actions, at certain times, for specific touchEvents

Tags: ios, swift

So my `UI` has many `UIButtons`, and I have an `"Action"` `Int` which cycles through 0-9.

I'd like to make it so when `"Action"` is `0`, only input from the 1st `UIButton` is registered. Once the user presses the 1st `UIButton` my code already advances the `"Action"` `Int` to `1`, at which point I'd like my program to only register input from the 2nd `UIButton`...and so forth.

I have my `UIButtons` in an array. So far I've found `UIButton.hidden` and `UIButton.enable` which I could toggle programmatically based off of `"Action"`

---

.hidden won't work because I want the button still visible.

.enable keeps it visible BUT...here's the catch.

Each button has 4 different actions `touchUpInside` `touchDragExit` `doubleTap:GestureRecognizer` and `longPress:GestureRecognizer` as well as a `func` that collects the `UIButtons` in a "swipe" array when Panned-over and performs those buttons' `touchDragExit` upon Pan finish.

**And** I want `longPress:GestureRecognizer` to NEVER become inactive.

**And** I want the Pan func to still be able to collect the buttons in the array as long as the first button is == `"Action"`

**Any suggestions of other methods, or how I could make the .enable work for specific `touchEvents`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend enabling and disabling if you want certain gestures to remain working.

My initial thought would be to set a tag for each button when creating your array, then check against the current action value in the gesture handler.

Perhaps you may need a state variable for the pan collection to check whether it successfully started when the other buttons pick it up, depending on your implementation.

```
var buttonArray = [UIButton]()
var buttonCount = 10
var action = 0

func viewDidLoad {
   for var i = 0; i < buttonCount; ++i {
      var button = UIButton()
      button.tag = i

      button.setTarget(self, action:"didTap:", forControlEvent:.TouchUpInside)
      // Other actions
      button.setTarget(self, action:"didLongPress:", forControlEvent.LongPress)

      buttonArray.append(button)
   }
}

func didTap(sender:UIButton) {
   if action >= sender.tag {
      // Handle action
   }
}

// Other action handlers

func didLongPress(sender:UIButton) {
   // Always handle action
}
```

Comment: if an object's tag has not been set, does it's tag == nil?

Comment: In general, `.tag` was exactly what I was looking for. Anyone have a link to Apple docs on `.tag`. I couldn't find